# Changing CSS for last <li>

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists

I am wondering if there is some way to change a CSS attribute for the last `li` in a list using CSS.  I have looked into using `:last-child`, but this seems really buggy and I can't get it to work for me.  I will use JavaScript to do this if necessary, but I want to know if anyone can think up a solution in CSS.

Comment: I'm curious: why do you need this?

Comment: Hi strager: I am making a navigation bar and want the properties of the last element to be different then the rest of them.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

`:last-child` is really the only way to do it without modifying the HTML - but assuming you can do that, the main option is just to give it a `class="last-item"`, then do:

```
li.last-item { /* ... */ }
```

Obviously, you can automate this in the dynamic page generation language of your choice. Also, there is a [`lastChild`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html) JavaScript property in the W3C DOM.

Here's an example of doing what you want in [**Prototype**](http://prototypejs.org):

```
$$("ul").each(function(x) { $(x.lastChild).addClassName("last-item"); });
```

Or even more simply:

```
$$("ul li:last-child").each(function(x) { x.addClassName("last-item"); });
```

In [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com), you can write it even more compactly:

```
$("ul li:last-child").addClass("last-item");
```

Also note that this *should* work without using the actual `last-child` CSS selector - rather, a JavaScript implementation of it is used - so it should be less buggy and more reliable across browsers.

Comment: Nice that you incorporated my answer into yours after I posted it.

Comment: Sorry - I was in the middle of posting the JQuery equivalent of the Prototype code I had already posted. If you would like, I can edit the JQuery part out.

Comment: No problem.  I was actually saying that it validates at least part of how I've done this.

Comment: Sorry again for misunderstanding :). Technically, your code is 10x better - it actually works! (Typo will be fixed in 10..9..)

Comment: jQuery does let the browser handle the selection if it understands `:last-child` though.

Answer (score 65):

I've done this with pure CSS (probably because I come from the future - 3 years later than everyone else :P )

Supposing we have a list:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><span>Category 1</span></li>
  <li><span>Category 2</span></li>
  <li><span>Category 3</span></li>
</ul>
```

Then we can easily make the text of the last item red with:

```
ul#nav li:last-child span {
   color: Red;
}
```

Comment: By far the cleanest solution (if supported obviously).

Comment: The selector does the trick "ul#nav li:last-child span" works and "#nav li:last-child span" does not. While technically both points to the same element , the first one is more specific.  Salutes to the "man from future"

Comment: +1 for the "man from the future" ;) - although strictly speaking, two years down you're a man from the past :P

Comment: but because he wrote it 2 years ago doesn't mean he's not from the future, rather a man from the future with a past :)

Answer (score 12):

I usually combine CSS and JavaScript approaches, so that it works without JavaScript in all browsers but IE6/7, and in IE6/7 with JavaScript on (but not off), since they does not support the `:last-child` pseudo-class.

```
$("li:last-child").addClass("last-child");

li:last-child,li.last-child{ /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Just a minor correction, :last-child doesn't work on IE7 as well.

Answer (score 10):

You could use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and do it as such way

```
$("li:last-child").addClass("someClass");
```

Answer (score 7):

One alternative for IE7+ and other browsers may be to use `:first-child` instead, and invert your styles.

For example, if you're setting the margin on each `li`:

```
ul li {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
ul li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

You could replace it with this:

```
ul li {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
ul li:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

This will work well for some other cases like borders.

According to [sitepoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstchild), `:first-child` buggy, but only to the extent that it will select some root elements (the doctype or html), and may not change styles if other elements are inserted.

Answer (score 5):

**2015 Answer**: [CSS last-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) allows you to style the last item.

```
ul li:last-of-type { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually do this by creating a htc file (ex. last-child.htc):

```
<attach event="ondocumentready" handler="initializeBehaviours" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function initializeBehaviours() {
  this.lastChild.className += ' last-child';
}
</script>
```

And call it from my IE conditional css file with:

`ul { behavior: url("/javascripts/htc/last-child.htc"); }`

Whereas in my main css file I got:

```
ul li:last-child,
ul li.last-child {
  /* some code */
}
```

Another solution (albeit slower) that uses your existent css markup without defining any .last-child class would be Dean Edwards [ie7.js](http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/test/last-child.html) library.

Answer (score 2):

:last-child is CSS3 and has no IE support while :first-child is CSS2, I believe the following is the safe way to implement it using jquery

```
$('li').last().addClass('someClass');
```

Answer (score 2):

$('li').last().addClass('someClass');

if you have multiple

group
it will only select the last li.

Answer (score 0):

If you know there are three li's in the list you're looking at, for example, you could do this:

```
li + li + li { /* Selects third to last li */
}
```

In IE6 you can use expressions:

```
li {
    color: expression(this.previousSibling ? 'red' : 'green'); /* 'green' if last child */
}
```

I would recommend using a specialized class or Javascript (not IE6 expressions), though, until the `:last-child` selector gets better support.