# CSS ul li: Avoiding double borders

Tags: css, html-lists, border

I have a UL with

```
border: 1px solid grey;
```

it contains several LIs with

```
border-bottom: 1px dotted grey;
```

to keep the items apart visually. But now the last LI has the dotted border and the UL solid border! This looks annoying. How can I avoid that? Is there a way to put borders between LIs instead of after them?

Comment: Exact Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329841/changing-css-for-last-li

Answer (score 23, accepted):

CSS3 selectors can target `:first-child` or `:last-child`, like this:

```
ul {
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
li {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted grey;
}
li:last-child {
    border:none;
}
```

A working example: http://api.fatherstorm.com/test/4165384.php

Comment: Oh my god, that's brilliant. Thank you.

Comment: note that this will cause problems in IE6 if you have to support this piece of crap

Answer (score 12):

A smooth solution is to use the [plus (+) selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#adjacent-combinators) to style the list:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

You just add [the following css](http://jsfiddle.net/lundmikkel/ZrjtR/):

```
li + li {
     border-top: 1px dotted grey;
}
```

You avoid adding an extra selector and are able to keep the code more clean. Though depending on your needs you might want to check [browser compatibilty](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_adjacent_sibling) first.

Comment: FatherStorm's solution is the most common (and was my own first instinct), but this is more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Use a class or the CSS3 selector `:last-child` to remove the last `<li>` border-bottom

```
ul li:last-child { border-bottom:0; }
```

or

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li class="last">3</li>
</ul>

ul li.last { border-bottom:0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a different class to the last `li` which specifies to not show a border.