# How to display a line between the items of an unorderer list that have random number of li every time

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists

I'm doing this page that is made for the user to interact with the page and it'll have a list of pages that the user will determinate. So this list will be display in a div as an unordered list

about

location

runaway

and will have a random number of li's that will depend on the user. 
I want the list to have between the items a line, but in the last li in the bottom should not have any line and in the first in the top eather.

It should look like

```
                                 about
```

---

```
                                location
```

---

```
                                runaway
```

in my css I have:

li { border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6); padding-bottom: 5px;}

anyone knows how to do this? 
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using this jQuery to apply the css class?

```
$('li:not(:last)').addClass('test');
```

find an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/umupX/7/

**Note**: I've tried to use the css supplied by you. It seems to be failing in IE8 due to unsupported 'rgba'
**Note2**: I've tested the above in IE, Chrome and Firefox successfully (I would have prefered a pure css solution http://jsfiddle.net/8NZ2s/ but that one was failing in IE8)

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS property `:last-child`. Also, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329841/changing-css-for-last-li) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Some browsers support + but not :last-child, so in that case you can do this:

```
li + li {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

This means that the first list item doesn't get a top border.

Comment: @T B I just copied the original question.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with css:

```
li:first-child {*css for first li item*/}
li:last-child {/*css for last li item*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this:

```
ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D7DFE4;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
}
```

it basically hides the last divider using overflow:hidden and margin-bottom:-1

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li:not(:last)').css({
 'border-bottom": '1px solid black', 
 'padding-bottom": '5px'
}​)​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with a pseudo-element:

```
li:nth-child(even):before{
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    height: 1px; /* border width */
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
```