# Problem with selecting a nested last element

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML code with applied CSS.

I need all div with `cnt-list-box` in red but ONLY the LAST div `cnt-list-box` with different color.
Any ideas?

```
<div class="cnt-box-1">
    <div class="cnt-list-box">content 1</div>
    <div class="cnt-list-box">content 2</div>
    <div class="cnt-list-box">content 3</div>
    <div class="cnt-list-box">content 4</div>
    <div class="cnt-list-box">content 5</div>
</div>

.cnt-list-box
{
    background-color:Red;   
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329841/changing-css-for-last-li

Comment: Depending on your required browser-compatibility you could maybe use the `:last-of-type` pseudo-selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your example does work in FF and Webkit:
http://jsfiddle.net/meo/hwFYT/

As commented by usoban you should check:
[Changing CSS for last <li>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329841/changing-css-for-last-li)

PS: your incode comment is not a valid CSS comment. It produces a parsing error this is why it seams to work, but its no a good practice.

Comment: thanks for your answer it works! I also find a solution my self but your seems more net. THanks

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately I found by myself a reasonable solution to my problem.

```
.cnt-box-1 > .cnt-list-box:last-child
{
    background-color: Blue;   
}
```

Comment: meo your solution is perfect I will accept it in a couple of minutes, thanks for your time on this.