# Last of each class group

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So I have a sequence of `<tr>` elements and some of them have a special class:

```html
<tr>...</tr>
<tr class="special">...</tr>
<tr class="special">...</tr> <!-- this one -->
<tr>...</tr>
<tr class="special">...</tr>
<tr class="special">...</tr>
<tr class="special">...</tr> <!-- this one -->
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
```

How can I target the last of each special group (the ones marked with the comments) in my CSS?  Or should I change my markup? Note that any miraculous CSS3 selector is allowed.

Comment: See a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329841/changing-css-for-last-li

Comment: Add a `javascript` tag if you want to include Javascript answers. This is not possible with CSS & your current markup.

Comment: Good question. A :last-of-class selector would be useful, but alas it doesn't exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a selector for that, sorry. You'll have to change your markup somehow (easiest by adding a class to the last of each group).

Comment: Ok then, I will add a class. Thanks for the edit in the question by the way.

Comment: If you don't mind using jQuery to add the class, you should be able to do so with this one-liner: `$('tr:not(.special)').prev('tr.special').addClass('last');`

Answer (score 0):

What BoltClock said is true, there isn't. If there's a way for you to replace the `<tr>...</tr>` to the `</ul> <ul>`, you can use `ul tr.special:last-child`

Comment: Did you mean `tbody` rather than `ul`? This is a table, not a list.

Comment: hehe xD doing more things at the same time isn't that clever